# Should i run my database on a RDS or off an EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Initially for launch our database will be well within the limits of the ec2. We are wondering if there is any negative aspects associated with using the EC2 to hold our database and later switching to an RDS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be. You will have to migrate to the RDS instance though, which seems like a bother.

A RDS micro instance is only like $20-ish/month. So why not just bite the bullet and save yourself some time.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's better to run off of RDS and Amazon worry about the db maintenance.  I believe an RDS micro instance should give you decent performance if your app is not that big.